# Angular with Datepicker: minDate behaviour

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I don't understand why `date-min="dateMin"` with `$scope.dateMin = new Date();` doesn't work... But if I use `datepicker-options`, it works fine. Why? 
Here is an example:
[plnkr datePicker minDate example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pn9HjIhsTawtRC6gvEmE?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see at [angular bootstrap Datepicker documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) there is no `date-min` but only `minDate` at `datepicker-options` as you use it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. I was confused because I found that a lot of people were using a `date-min` attribute. But it never worked for me.